# Why isn't error login handling working in flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have been working on a Flask Authentication page for my website, but for some reason my error handling isn't working

Here is my app.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            if user is None:
                print("Invalid Credentials")
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Does anyone know why this

```
if user is None:
    print("Invalid Credit")
```

Is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax "if user is None:" will never trigger, because if user is None, you would never be inside your conditional statement above, "if user:"

If your goal is to create an action for wrong password, you need an else statement following the if bcrypt.check_password_hash. Add another else statement opposite of your conditional statement "if user" in order to determine if username exist in database.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        # username was found
        if user:
            # password is correct
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            # password is wrong
            else:
                print("Login Unsuccessful, Please check password")
        # username was not found
        else:
            print('Login Unsuccessful. Please check username')

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```